# every Fn::And object requires a list of at least 2 and at most 10 boolean parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can't make the following work in Cloudformation.

```
Conditions:

  EmptyBalancer:
    !Equals [!Ref BalancerName, '']

  EmptyAutoscaling:
    !Equals [!Ref AutoscalingName, '']

  NoLoadBalancerAndAutoscaling:
    !And [EmptyBalancer, EmptyAutoscaling]
```

The conditions do not compile. Resulting with a template error:

> every Fn::And object requires a list of at least 2 and at most 10
>   boolean parameters

Also tried other but same error

```
  NoLoadBalancerAndAutoscaling:
    !And [!Ref EmptyBalancer, !Ref EmptyAutoscaling]
```

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there. When using **!And** for [condition statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) with Cloudformation you need to call your conditions early, as you have in your example. Additionally, you also need to call reference to **!Condition** when calling inside a **!And** condition. Please see below using your example:

```
Conditions:
  EmptyBalancer: !Equals [!Ref BalancerName, ""]
  EmptyAutoscaling: !Equals [!Ref AutoscalingName, ""]
  NoLoadBalancerAndAutoscaling: !And 
      - !Condition EmptyBalancer
      - !Condition EmptyAutoscaling
```